# cant pass back text in a JavaScript componate (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so im trying to make a button display text in it but im having a hard time.

```
import React from "react"
import './Button.css'

const STYLES = 
[
  'btn--primary',
  'btn--outline'
]
const SIZES = [
    'btn--medium',
    'btn--large'
]

export const Button =({
  child,
  type,
  onClick,
  buttonStyle, 
  buttonSize
  }) =>
{

  const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle) ? buttonStyle : STYLES[0]

  const checkButtonSize =   SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0]

  return(
    <button className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`} onClick={onClick} 
    type={type}>
      {child}
      </button>
  )

}
```

if i just put plain text where child is it will display but if i try to do it in my navbar it will just make a button with no text.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {MenuItems} from './MenuItems'
import {Button} from '../Button.js'
import './Navbar.css'
class Navbar extends Component{
  state = { clicked : false}
  handleClick = () =>
  {
    this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
  }

  render()
  {
    return(
      <nav className="NavBarItems">
        <h1 className='navbar-logo'>React<i className='fab fa-react'></i></h1>
        <div className='menu-icon' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <i className={this.state.clicked ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}></i>

        </div>
        <ul className={this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active':'nav-menu'}>
          {MenuItems.map((item,index)=>{
           return(
            <li key={index}>
              <a className={item.cname} href={item.url}>
                {item.title}
                </a>
                
                </li>
           )})}
        </ul>
        <Button>Sign Up</Button> 
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar
```

Thank you in advance for anyone who has an idea on fixing this.

also sorry i dont know the proper terms, I do more python, java, and c++ coding so this is a new world to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the prop 'children' here instead of 'child' as its the official data type for your use case, can refer to this for more info https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891

So in this case you can modify your button file as such:

```
import React from "react"
import './Button.css'

const STYLES = 
[
  'btn--primary',
  'btn--outline'
]
const SIZES = [
    'btn--medium',
    'btn--large'
]

export const Button =({
  children,
  type,
  onClick,
  buttonStyle, 
  buttonSize
  }) =>
{

  const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle) ? buttonStyle : STYLES[0]

  const checkButtonSize =   SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0]

  return(
    <button className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`} onClick={onClick} 
    type={type}>
      {children}
      </button>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the built-in property `children`, this name is used by convention and it is always plural. It will be set to whatever you put between the `<Button>` opening and closing tags.

In other words, rename the `child` destructuring property to **`children`** in the Button component, both in the header + where it is used.